# How to join multiple functions to apply to a file? Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

Continuing my studies in haskell, I need to apply several functions to a file. I researched and found some tips, but it's not working, I'm having problems with the type system, can help me? I make this:

```
import Prelude hiding (Word, lines)
import Data.Char
import System.IO
import Data.List hiding (lines)

type Doc = String
type Line = String
type Word = String

makeIndex :: Doc -> [([Int], Word)]
makeIndex = lines . numLines . allNumWords . sortLs . makelists . almalgamate . shorten

lines :: Doc -> [Line]
lines [] = []
lines texto = takeWhile(/='\n') texto:(lines.dropWhile(=='\n').dropWhile(/='\n')) texto

numLines :: [Line] -> [(Int, Line)]
numLines texto = zip [1.. length texto] texto

numWord :: (Int, Line) -> [(Int, Word)]
numWord (number, line) = [(number, word) | word <- divide line]

divide :: String -> [Word]
divide st = split (dropSpace st)

split :: String -> [Word]
split [] = []
split st = (getWord st) : split (dropSpace (dropWord st))

getWord :: String -> String
getWord [] = []
getWord (x:xs) | elem x whitespace = (x:xs)
               | otherwise = dropWord xs

whitespace :: String
whitespace = ['\n', '\t', ' ']

dropSpace :: String -> String
dropSpace [] = []
dropSpace (x:xs) | elem x whitespace = dropSpace xs
                 | otherwise = (x:xs)

dropWord :: String -> String
dropWord [] = []
dropWord (x:xs) | elem x whitespace = (x:xs)
                | otherwise = dropWord xs          

allNumWords :: [(Int, Line)] -> [(Int, Word)]
allNumWords = concat.map numPalavra

sortLs :: [(Int, Word)] -> [(Int, Word)]
sortLs [] = []
sortLs (a:x) = sortLs [b | b <- x, compare b a] ++ [a] ++ sortLs [b | b <- x, compare a b]
                where compare (n1, w1) (n2, w2) = (w1 < w2) || (w1 == w2 && n1 < n2)

makelist :: [(Int, Word)] -> [([Int], Word)]
makelist = map mklis 
             where mklis (num, word) = ([num], word)

almalgamate :: [([Int], Word)] -> [([Int], Word)]
almalgamate [] = []
almalgamate [a] = [a]
almalgamate ((n1, w1) : (n2, w2) : rest) | w1 /= w2 = (n1, w1) : almalgamate ((n2, w2) : rest)
                                         | otherwise = almalgamate ((n1++n2, w1) : rest)

shorten :: [([Int], Word)] -> [([Int], Word)]
shorten = filter long
           where long (num, palavra) = length palavra > 4
```

In the compiler the error is:

```
in line 18
Coldn't match type `[Char]' -> ([Int], Word)'  
Expected type: Doc -> [([Int], Word)]  
Actual type: [([Int], Word] -> [Line]  
int the expression (repeat all the functions)  
in an equation for 'makeIndex' (repeat all the functions)
```

That's same error shown at all the functions call in the makeindex.

```
GHCi, version 8.0.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\makeindex.hs, interpreted )

C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\makeindex.hs:17:6: error:  
    * Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `([Int], Word)'  
      Expected type: Doc -> [([Int], Word)]  
        Actual type: [([Int], Word)] -> [String]  
    * In the expression:  
        lines  
        . numLines  
          . allNumWords . sortLs . converte . almalgamate . shorten
      In an equation for `makeIndex':  
          makeIndex  
            = lines  
              . numLines  
                . allNumWords . sortLs . makelist . almalgamate . shorten  

C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\makeindex.hs:18:6: error:  
    * Couldn't match type `(Int, Line)' with `Char'  
      Expected type: [([Int], Word)] -> String  
        Actual type: [([Int], Word)] -> [(Int, Line)]  
    * In the second argument of `(.)', namely  
        `numLines  
         . allNumWords . sortLs . makelist . almalgamate . shorten'
      In the expression:  
        lines  
        . numLines  
          . allNumWords . sortLs . converte . almalgamate . shorten
      In an equation for `makeIndex':  
          makeIndex  
            = lines  
              . numLines  
                . allNumWords . sortLs . makelist . almalgamate . shorten  

C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\makeindex.hs:19:6: error:  
    * Couldn't match type `(Int, Word)' with `[Char]'  
      Expected type: [([Int], Word)] -> [Line]  
        Actual type: [([Int], Word)] -> [(Int, Word)]  
    * In the second argument of `(.)', namely  
        `allNumWords . sortLs . makelist . almalgamate . shorten'  
      In the second argument of `(.)', namely  
        `numLines  
         . allNumWords . sortLs . makelist . almalgamate . shorten'  
      In the expression:  
        lines  
        . numLines  
          . allNumWords . sortLs . makelist . almalgamate . shorten  

C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\makeindex.hs:21:6: error:  
    * Couldn't match type `[Int]' with `Int'  
      Expected type: [([Int], Word)] -> [(Int, Word)]  
        Actual type: [([Int], Word)] -> [([Int], Word)]  
    * In the second argument of `(.)', namely  
        `converte . almalgamate . shorten'  
      In the second argument of `(.)', namely  
        `sortLs . converte . almalgamate . shorten'  
      In the second argument of `(.)', namely  
        `allNumWords . sortLs . makelist . almalgamate . shorten'  

C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\makeindex.hs:22:6: error:  
    * Couldn't match type `[Int]' with `Int'  
      Expected type: [([Int], Word)] -> [(Int, Word)]  
        Actual type: [([Int], Word)] -> [([Int], Word)]  
    * In the second argument of `(.)', namely `almalgamate . shorten'  
      In the second argument of `(.)', namely  
        `converte . almalgamate . shorten'  
      In the second argument of `(.)', namely  
        `sortLs . converte . almalgamate . shorten'  
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

This are the problems, an match types problem?  I'm so sorry for my bad description of the problem, in the first posting.

Comment: What's not working? What problems with the type system? What errors? What are the other functions you are defining? You could probably supply fewer details in your question, but it would be difficult.

Comment: Please *edit your question* to include the full error message. Please also provide the type signatures and brief descriptions (or full code) of numLines, allNumWords, sortLs, makeList, amalgamate, and shorten. Without this information, it is impossible to answer your question. Please also explain, in the body of the question, exactly what you intend your function to do. Making an index of a file is not nearly precise enough.

Comment: I changed the post, i'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you've mixed up the order of the arguments to `(.)`. It's defined (essentially) as

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
(f . g) x = f (g x)
```

So it applies `g` first, and then applies `f` to the result.

Your program will typecheck if you string up the functions in the opposite order:

```
makeIndex = shorten . almalgamate . converte . sortLs
              . allNumWords . numLines . lines
```

Alternatively, you can use `(>>>)`, which is a flipped version of `(.)`:

```
import Control.Category ((>>>))

makeIndex = lines >>> numLines >>> allNumWords >>> sortLs
              >>> converte >>> almalgamate >>> shorten
```

Since you still haven't said what you expect the program to *do*, I can't speak to whether the modified version is actually *correct*, but it does compile.

Comment: Thanks for the help, my objective in this code is make a index of words, according their occurrence in a file text. But, my problem is the work with some functions together. 

I understood how make this work, thanks again for your patience.